# update the app with a button - android studio

Tags: java, android

How to update the app with a button?
Ex: I am uploading images to the firebase storage, I want when I add an image to a section it will be visible.

Currently: Refresh occurs when the application is closed from processes and reopened.
I use Android 6 and above.

What are the ways to update the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Firebase Cloud function to trigger events and send notifications to the app. handle notification in app accordingly

Comment: I am not able to get your question?

Comment: please, more info..  i want to update the app with a button..